# Deploy Jhipster on openshift

Tags: java, openshift, jhipster

I deploy a Jhipster app on openshift and i have the following error.

The first message it perhaps confusing, but it s the second time i try to deploy, so mean the code is yet pushed

```
Adding files for initial commit
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Re-pushing the existing "deploy/openshift" build...
```

To deploy we need to modify hooks as executable in remote repository. But this files are not pushed by default (are included in gitignore), so i force to be commited and launch the following cmd

```
Chmod action hooks
× { [Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/build && git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/start && git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/stop && git commit -m "Chmod""
error: deploy/openshift/.openshift/action_hooks/build: cannot add to the index - missing --add option?
fatal: Unable to process path deploy/openshift/.openshift/action_hooks/build
]
  killed: false,
  code: 128,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c "git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/build && git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/start && git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/stop && git commit -m "Chmod""' }

Uploading your initial application code.
 This may take several minutes depending on your connection speed...
× ssh: connect to host ------i remove host--------- port 22: Bad file number

× fatal: Could not read from remote repository.


Why the cmd git update-index fail, is on relation by 22: bad file
```

Regards and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably already attempted to deploy this once.  As such you now have a "deploy" folder in your project root associated with your old openshift assigned git repository (which you have since deleted and is unreachable).  Simply remove/delete the "deploy" folder from your root and try again.  You can confirm this is happening by a line at the top when you launch the deploy command which states "found existing git remote".  Hopefully this is not a misguided answer and helps...